# How to access the first element of the checkbox array without using each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery event that will collect the list of selected checkboxes and I am currently experimenting their behaviours by trying to access them 1 by 1.

```
$('#sub').click(function () {

    var cb = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    var count = cb.length;

    alert(cb[0].prop('checked'));

    if (count == 0) {
        alert('No subjects selected');
        return false;
    } else {
        return confirm(count + " row(s) selected, proceed?");
    }
});
```

Accessing `cb` directly won't work for some reason.

I need to do something like this :

```
 cb.each(function (i) {
    alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

But this will require me to loop through all of them when I only need the first element of the array, to see if it's true.

Are there any methods and can someone tell me why my first approach didn't work? I tried using `for loop` but no luck.

Comment: give that checkbox an ID and select that checkbox using ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to check whether at least one item is selected, since `cb` has only checked items you can just check whether the set has atleast one item like

```
$('#sub').click(function () {
    var cb = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

    if (!cb.length) {
        alert('No subjects selected');
        return false;
    } else {
        return confirm(count + " row(s) selected, proceed?");
    }
```

Comment: As an option you can also use `:checkbox` selector instead of `input[type...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am trying to access them 1 by1 through hard coding but `cb[0].prop` won't work.

Comment: @Tushar is there a difference when using `:checkbox and input[type='checkbox']`?

Comment: if you want to access one by one give each an ID and access using it @CarlosMiguelColanta

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Tushar I think they are the same I am just wondering why you suggested using :checkbox when they are the same thank you for clarification

Comment: @Pekka less typing :)

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta all elements in `cb` will be checked because you are using the `:checked` selector to obtain `cb`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Just rephrasing for better clarification `all elements in cb will be checked` ---> _`cb` will contain all the `checked` elements_

Comment: What's the difference between accessing the jquery object and the dom? mostly on this code `alert(cb[0].checked);` will work instead of `alert(cb[0].prop('checked'));` aren't they supposed to access the same thing? aka the `checked` property of the first checkbox.   I changed my code to `var cb = $("input[type='checkbox']");`.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta `cb[0]` will refer to the dom element, which does not have a function like `prop` so `cb[0].prop('checked')` will throw an error

Comment: Ahhhh i see, so `cb[0]` isn't wrapped anymore unlike jquery objects?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta you can use `cb.eq(0).is(':checked')` - here `.eq(0)` will return a jQuery object reference for the first element - also you can use the `:checked` selector as shown

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta yes.... what you are trying to do is the same as `document.getElementById(someid).prop()` - as you know it will fail

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

```
alert(cb.eq(0).prop('checked'));
```

or `cb[0]` will return dom object

```
alert(cb[0].checked);
```

Ref : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta : returns dom object not jQuery object

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta it will always be checked because `cb` will have only checked items

Comment: hmm i see, what if i removed the `:checked`. will `cb[0].prp` work?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: I thought of the `cb[0].checked` earlier but it didn't appear on visual studio's intellisense. well thank you

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var cb = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

Doesn't return a single element, it potentially returns many.

This will target the first checked checkbox:

```
var cb = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked:first");
```

This will target the first checkbox regardless of state:

```
var cb = $("input[type='checkbox']:first");
```